# Undefined end-point http://localhost:8010/undefined/

Tags: javascript, express, axios, endpoint

I am trying to send data from front-end to back-end. Here is my front:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL}`, // process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL = http://localhost:8010
})


export const postTip = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post(`post-tip`, payload);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
};
```

And here is back-end:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const tipController = require('../controllers/tips/tipController')

router.post('post-tip', tipController.postTip);
```

That function `tipController.postTip` actually just receive and shows data, but when I trigger this end-point I get error: `POST http://localhost:8010/undefined/post-tip 404 (Not Found)`. So, what's wrong with end-point and how can I make it work? Also, I have no idea, where does this `undefined` come from? Am I missing something?

Comment: `Also, I have no idea, where does this undefined come from?` Probably from `process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL`

Comment: I wrote a comment - `// process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL = http://localhost:8010`

Comment: it may not be defined at runtime even know you think it is. try `baseURL: process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL || 'foo-bar',` and see if `undefined` is replaced with `foo-bar`

Comment: No, this `process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL` works correctly, I just checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my mistake. Actually `process.env.BASE_FRONT_URL` was really `undefined`, so, I made it like that:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8084',
})


export const postTip = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post(`post-tip`, payload);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
};
```

But the most important thing is that on back-end I have to use the same port (8084)